# Tensorflow object detection API not detecting bounding boxes

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, object-detection-api

My question is similar to [Tensorflow Object Detection API does not detect objects correctly/does not detect objects at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484066/tensorflow-object-detection-api-does-not-detect-objects-correctly-does-not-detec) but it is a different use case and this question isn't solved.

I am using object detection API for transfer learning in order to identify faces (1 class). The pretrained model being used is ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017. This was run for 1.5 hrs and for 3,500 iterations and the loss was around 4.5 (there was a sharp drop in the first few iterations as expected so I am assuming this is not the best model yet but I should get discernible results)

I then used the latest checkpoint, exported inference graph, made modifications to the object_detection_tutorial notebook. However this just outputs my test images without any bounding boxes (NOTE:- the original notebook runs fine and I am able to see the boxes, so my guess is there is some issue with my model which I am not able to figure out)

I am pasting results which I used to debug. Seems like the bounding box coordinates have 1 and 0s. I also played around by changing min_score_thresh in visualization_utils.py but that does not help either.

Config file excerpts(made modifications to a sample. changed-num_classes to 1 and paths to my relavant files)

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }

fine_tune_checkpoint: "ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017/model.ckpt"

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "training/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "training/face-detection.pbtxt"
}
```

**Sample output of detection_boxes**

```
array([[0.        , 0.2554323 , 1.        , 0.7534608 ],
       [0.3012189 , 0.        , 0.70924723, 1.        ],
       [0.18439636, 0.        , 0.817055  , 1.        ],
       [0.05466348, 0.06271043, 0.95918256, 0.94578576],
       [0.5260097 , 0.07892245, 0.97103214, 1.        ],
       [0.27985883, 0.5130247 , 1.        , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 0.41663095, 0.5991725 , 1.        ],
       [0.03816789, 0.        , 0.4441032 , 1.        ],
       [0.        , 0.5875985 , 1.        , 0.9825353 ],
       [0.5518031 , 0.        , 0.9699122 , 0.9448744 ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.6656574 , 0.7552371 ],
       [0.        , 0.07883103, 1.        , 0.49962282],
       [0.04292154, 0.57037276, 1.        , 0.9573701 ],
       [0.05089287, 0.00120801, 0.46899152, 1.        ],
       [0.43095234, 0.31733978, 1.        , 1.        ],
```

**Output of detection_classess**

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
   1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**sample output of detection_scores** low scores but changing threshold does not help

```
   3.20677400e-01, 3.19893241e-01, 3.14980447e-01, 3.09631795e-01,
   2.53045678e-01, 2.52637416e-01, 2.52323598e-01, 2.41894022e-01,
   2.40268022e-01, 2.40083978e-01, 2.36307651e-01, 2.15435311e-01,
   2.14362189e-01, 2.13490084e-01, 2.12984398e-01, 2.10590839e-01,
   2.03191489e-01, 1.66917413e-01, 1.64012805e-01, 1.60537049e-01,
   6.71069846e-02, 6.55404702e-02, 3.69835161e-02, 3.63573395e-02,
   3.15450728e-02, 2.46258732e-02, 2.34935526e-02, 2.04152763e-02,
   1.82382613e-02, 1.56786684e-02, 1.50712561e-02, 1.47904372e-02,
   1.45556601e-02, 1.41305756e-02, 1.14051756e-02, 1.02278581e-02,
   9.46425926e-03, 8.77886359e-03, 8.67216382e-03, 7.98975583e-03
```

Comment: Is `from_detection_checkpoint` true or false?

Comment: from_detection_checkpoint is set to True

Comment: To me 4.5K iterations sounds not a lot, so it might be that your model hasn't converged yet. It also depends on the learning rate you're using.
BTW, there's a pre-trained SSD-MobileNetV2 model on faces from OIv4 you can check out here: http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/facessd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_320x320_open_image_v4.tar.gz